# Topological spaces with ACC on closed sets

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $\mathcal{U}$ be a base of closed sets for $X$, i.e.

i) every closed set in $X$ is a finite union of the elements of $\mathcal{U}$.

ii) $\mathcal{U}$ is closed under arbitrary intersections.

Is it true that the following two statements are equivalent?

1- $X$ has ascending chain conditions on closed sets.

2- every ascending chain of the elements of $\mathcal{U}$ terminates.

Comment: Using duality, the natural concept of base if closed sets seem to me that every closed set is intersection of elements of the base and that the base is closed with respect finite unions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Let $X$ be an infinite set, and consider the topology where exactly the finite subsets of $X$ and $X$ itself are closed.

Then let $\mathcal U:=\left\{\,\{x\}\ \mid\ x\in X\right\}\ \cup\ \{\emptyset\}$.

This satisfies condition 2, however $X$ has a proper ascending chain of closed sets.

Comment: thank you for the example. What happens if we add the requirement "$\emptyset$ does not belong to $\mathcal{U}$"?